# Correct way to remove folder name from website URL

Tags: html, .htaccess

There are a couple of posts that cover the question of removing folder paths from URLs, but none of the answers explain how to link the page using html after adding the `.htaccess` code.

The folder structure looks like this:

```
root
    .htaccess
    index.html
    folder
        games.html
```

I am using the following code to remove the folder path "folder" from the URL.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder/$1 [L]
```

**Would the correct way to "load" the page `games.html` from the index.html file be:**

```
<a href="games.html">games</a>
```

**and wouldn't it be a conflictual issue if i have a `games.html` file in the root folder as well?**

Using the method below includes the folder name in the URL. Is it possible to remove the folder name from the URL whilst still being able to link to the page using the entire path?

```
<a href="folder/games.html">games</a>
```

I would appreciate if my provided `.htaccess` code can be simplified or if there is a better way to write the code.

Comment: If `games.html` is present in both root and `folder` directories then what is the desired behavior?

Comment: @anubhava Thank you so much for a response. It was a general question regarding the behaviour of which would be used out of those two files. I was asking that to get an understanding of how the .htaccess would run and what it would do. What I am really asking is, in the current state of the .htaccess, would I be right to assume that I should enter `<a href="games.html">games</a>` in the `index.html` (without the entire path) to display the expected URL for the website (a URL without the "folder" name in the URL.)

Comment: @anubhava To add more information to the previous comment. I was wondering about having two games.html (one in root and one in "folder") because I wish to know if the .htaccess code "removes" the folder, as if it doesn't exist and if the `games.html` is put in the root. (I do understand that it doesn't actually removes the folder.)

Comment: @anubhava So all in all, the question I have is: Would the correct way to direct the user from `index.html` to `games.html` after adding the code to .htaccess be: `<a href="games.html">games</a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have this rule in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ folder/$1 [L]
```

Let me answer each question as I understand.

Q1. What should be correct html code for having a link?
A1. You can have:

```
<a href="games.html">games</a>
```

Q2. If `games.html` exists in root directory then which file will be shown?
A2. Apache will present `games.html` from root because of `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` condition which rewrites to `folder/` only if file doesn't exist in request.

Q3. What should be the correct rule?
A3. It is better to have your rule as:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ folder/$1 [L]
```

This way you can avoid infinite looping if rewritten file or directory doesn't exist in `folder/` directory.

Comment: This answered all of my questions perfectly! Thank you so much for all the help!